# Creating a queue using two stack, but make enqueuing O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, task-queue, enqueue

Is there a way to implement a queue using two stacks, but with enqueuing 0(1)?

I have been learning how to do a queue and one of the questions that I've been trying to find an answer for is how can I optimise a queue using two stacks. The code that I've impemented seems to have a worst runtime.

Below is my code, could I've approached this differently?

```
class Queue:
def __init__(self):
    self.s1 = []
    self.s2 = []

def enqueue(self, item):
    while len(self.s1) != 0:
        self.s2.append(self.s1.pop())
    self.s1.append(item)
    while len(self.s2) != 0:
        self.s1.append(self.s2.pop())

def dequeue(self):
    if len(self.s1) == 0:
        raise IndexError("Cannot pop from an empty queue")
    return self.s1.pop()
```

Queue()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually you can implement queue using 2 stacks with enqueuing O(1), by dequeuing O(n).
Here is an example, using your code:

```
def enqueue(self, item):
    self.s1.append(item)

def dequeue(self):
    if len(self.s1) == 0:
        raise IndexError("Cannot pop from an empty queue")

    queue_head = None

    # Search for the first item put in queue
    while len(self.s1) != 1:
        self.s2.append(self.s1.pop())

    # Save the item while we restore s1's data
    queue_head = self.s1.pop()

    while len(self.s2) != 0:
        self.s1.append(self.s2.pop())
    
    return queue_head
```

If you can't make both enqueuing and dequeuing to be O(1), and must choose one to be with higher complexity(Usually the one you will use the most).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have both enqueue and dequeue run in *amortized* O(1) (assuming `append` and `pop` are both O(1)). The idea is being lazy and not moving elements from `s1` to `s2` unless you absolutely have to.

```
def enqueue(self, item):
  self.s1.append(item)

def dequeue(self):
  if len(self.s2) == 0:
    while (len(self(s1)) > 0):
      s2.append(s1.pop())
  if len(self.s2) == 0:
    raise IndexError("Cannot pop from an empty queue")
  return s2.pop()
```

An element is appended to `s1`, gets moved to `s2` exactly once, and gets popped from `s2`. A sequence of N `enqueue` and `dequeue` operations takes O(N) time.